# The use of a data array in the d3.js scatter file instead of an external data file

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have the javascript of the scatter d3.js library:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.point {
fill: steelblue;
stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.6"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

 // Coerce the strings to numbers.
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.x = +d.x;
d.y = +d.y;
});

// Compute the scales’ domains.
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; })).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; })).nice();

// Add the x-axis.
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

 // Add the y-axis.
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

// Add the points!
svg.selectAll(".point")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });
});

</script>
```

The file:data.cvs

```
x,y
5,90
25,30
45,50
65,55
85,25
```

Instead of reading the data from a cvs file I added an array to the javascript and tried to extract x and y values directly from this array:

```
var rows = new array(
 array(0,0),
 array(90,90),
 array(59,70),
 array(65,77),
 array(85,66)
  );
```

How can I use the array rows in order to obtain the same result ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array of hash:

```
var data = [{"x":"5","y":"90"},{"x":"25","y":"30"},{"x":"45","y":"50"},
{"x":"65","y":"55"},{"x":"85","y":"25"}];
```

Or write a function to convert your array of arrays to this array of hash.

```
var rows = new Array(
  Array(0,0),
  Array(90,90),
  Array(59,70),
  Array(65,77),
  Array(85,66)
);

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  data.push({x: rows[i][0], y: rows[i][1]});
}

// Coerce the strings to numbers.
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
});
```

Here's the live code:

http://vida.io/documents/THpmgQDARSWPJqGG5

Comment: The problem is the data in the array is an input in my javascript that coudn' be edit. Because the same data can be an input for different graph libaries, this is way the format of the array have to be general as mention above. Any idea please?

Comment: another question please, here is the xaxis and the y axis depends on the values given in the array every one of them starts from the value min and stop in the value max. Can we change the graduation to be independent from the user values?

Comment: Can you log another question for it? I'll answer in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846861/how-to-define-a-static-xaxis-and-y-axis-javascript

Comment: Looks like someone has answered before me :)