# how to define a static xaxis and y axis, javascript d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

the x axis and the y axis depends on the values given in the array every one of them starts from the value min and stop in the value max. Can we change the segmentation to be independent from the user values?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.point {
 fill: steelblue;
stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.6"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {

 // Coerce the strings to numbers.
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.x = +d.x;
d.y = +d.y;
});

// Compute the scales’ domains.
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; })).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; })).nice();

// Add the x-axis.
 svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

// Add the y-axis.
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
 .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

 // Add the points!
 svg.selectAll(".point")
 .data(data)
 .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up"))
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });
  });

 </script>
```

The file:data.cvs

```
x,y
5,90
25,30
45,50
65,55
85,25
```

Comment: What is variable `d3`? Cannot find its declaration.

Comment: What are the user values and what are they used for?

Comment: I just edited the code, d3 is a library that allows user to built d3 objects like in this case scatter, and the data about x and y positions are located in an external file or an internal data array

Comment: you should add d3 to the tags and the question title

Comment: what you want exact ?

Comment: This two lines are responsible of drawing the xaxis and yaxis depending on the values of x and y given in the file:

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; })).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; })).nice();

I tried to edit them in oder to obtain a static segmantation for the two axis but it didnt work.

Comment: can you give required output graph as a image

Comment: as you can see here if you change vida.io/documents/THpmgQDARSWPJqGG5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think that your asking if you can set a custom range of ticks or if you can set a custom range for each axis.  Well it's the same answer yes.

You can customise a the tick marks using `axis.tickValues([custom range of values)]`.

You can set a custom range for the axis in domain call.  You can use a custom range [0,100] for instance such as posted above [vida.io](http://vida.io/documents/THpmgQDARSWPJqGG5) and also in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uvoFUmI/3/edit?js,output), so `.domain([0,100])`.  In the jsbin there are a couple of other ways you can customise range of the axis that are commented out.  Just turn them on and reload to see what they do. Don't forget to hit the run with js in the top right hand corner.

Using the d3.extent on the data returns the max and min of the array as specified in the assessor.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I am searching for: axis.tickValues([custom range of values)] thank you :)